# Did my $ mv '*.mobi' command concatenate my files?

Tags: files, directory, mv

While consolidating ebooks, I came across what appeared to be a handy fix for my specific operation; namely, I wanted to move all mobi files from different sub-folders in to one central folder named, imaginatively, 'mobi' ...

```
   $ find -name '*.mobi' -exec mv {} /mobi \;
```

And, yes, I did make a back up... exactly one directory above. And only realized what I had done until afterwards. (Originals **and** backup moved/gone.)

After some searching, I found what appears to be a folder but looks like a .mobi file in my root directory. It's about 1.5mb (from 30 ebooks); opening in Atom gives me gibberish (not code).

I assume this is some sort of dastardly ammalgamation of my previous files, melted grotesquely in to each other like the thing from The Thing.

Is there a way to undo my foolishness?

Comment: I cannot think of any circumstances under which `mv` would ever concatenate files. What actually happened depends on whether or not `/mobi` existed as a directory before the operation and whether there were any pair of source files with the same filenames.

Comment: And to prevent mistakes like these, it's a good idea to (1) always use `mv -i` (possibly with shell alias), (2) always end directories with a trailing `/`.

Answer (score 7):

The command you ran will have executed `mv <file> /mobi` for each
`<file>` that it found. There are several possible outcomes:

1. `/mobi` existed before, as a directory that your user is allowed to
   write into: then each of your mobi files is now inside directory
   `/mobi` (if any two had the same name, one of them will have
   overwritten the other);
2. either `/mobi` existed before as a file your user is allowed to
   overwrite, or it did not exist but your user is allowed to create
   files under `/`: then each of you mobi files will have overwritten,
   in sequence, the file `/mobi`, which now has, as its contents, the
   last of the files that `find` found;
3. otherwise, all of the `mv` commands should have failed, and nothing
   was moved.

Scenario (2) really only sounds likely if you ran your command as root
(which the `$` hints against). In that case, all your files except the
last one that `mv` operated on are lost. I can't think of a sensical
way that `mv` would concatenate files.